# Docker Squid not enforcing time acl in configuration

Tags: docker, squid, access-control-list, arm

I have a squid running in docker, which is not enforcing the time ACLs that are defined in the configuration. I'me using https://hub.docker.com/r/ubuntu/squid running on arm

This is my configuration in **squid.conf**:

```
acl localnet src 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255  # RFC 1122 "this" network (LAN)
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 100.64.0.0/10      # RFC 6598 shared address space (CGN)
acl localnet src 169.254.0.0/16     # RFC 3927 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12      # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src fc00::/7           # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10          # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl client1 src 192.168.1.89/32
# times below are in UTC
acl weekday_access time MTWH 6:00-20:30
acl friday_access time F 6:00-21:00
acl saturday_access time A 6:00-21:00
acl sunday_access time S 6:00-20:30


acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http

http_access allow client1 weekday_access
http_access allow client1 friday_access
http_access allow client1 saturday_access
http_access allow client1 sunday_access

http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager !client1
http_access deny manager client1
include /etc/squid/conf.d/*.conf
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all

http_port 3128

coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern \/(Packages|Sources)(|\.bz2|\.gz|\.xz)$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern \/Release(|\.gpg)$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern \/InRelease$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern \/(Translation-.*)(|\.bz2|\.gz|\.xz)$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
```

and this is the configuration in **/etc/squid/conf.d/debian.conf**

```
#
# Squid configuration settings for Debian
#

# Logs are managed by logrotate on Debian
logfile_rotate 0

# For extra security Debian packages only allow
# localhost to use the proxy on new installs
#
http_access allow localnet
```

It happens that the access is never cut off for the client1

Can someone help in point what is wrong with the configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to deny the client before the include

```
include /etc/squid/conf.d/*.conf
```

Since the include allows the client to connect.